I need to assign just the Item Description column text as a variable in Power Automate Desktop
SQL Query info
I am able to assign the whole row as the description variable with %queryresult[0]% but I want to extract just the info under Item Description for the description. Not sure how I would adjust the above.
Below are the things I have tried.
%QueryResult'ItemDescription'%
%QueryResult[0,1]%

If you want to extract the first value in the Item Description column you can use the following:
%queryresult[0]['Item Description']% 

OR
%queryresult[0][0]% 


if that answer helped, be sure to accept it as an answer
